# Undefined reference to explicitly instantiated template function

Tags: c++, templates, g++, clang++, explicit-instantiation

I have a class with a template method that is declared in a header and defined in a cpp file, so

```
// A.h - declaration
struct A
{
    template<typename T = int> void fun();
};
```

and then

```
// A.cpp - definition
#include <iostream>
#include "A.h"

template<typename T> void A::fun()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world template" << std::endl;
}

// Explicit instantiation
template void A::fun<int>();
```

Now, somewhere else, in a test, I have

```
#include "A.h"

int main ()
{
    A a;
    a.fun();
}
```

and since I explicitly instantiated the function for `int` template parameter, all is well. Or should be!

My code links fine with GCC 7.3.0 but fails to link with clang 6, which reports an undefined reference to function `fun`.

What's going on here? Is there anything else that I should take care of? Perhaps something that GCC takes for granted while clang doesn't?

Thanks!

**Edit**

@WhozCraig, @Neil Butterworth here are the linking commands for the two toolchains.

GCC:

```
/usr/bin/g++  -g   CMakeFiles/test_generator.dir/generator/generator.cpp.o CMakeFiles/test_generator.dir/test_utils.cpp.o  -o test_generator -Wl,-rpath,/home/mleoni/PhD/ABI/libcellml/build/src:/home/mleoni/PhD/ABI/libcellml/build/tests/gtest ../src/libcellmld.so.0.1.0 gtest/libgtest_main.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so gtest/libgtest.so -lpthread
```

clang:

```
/usr/bin/clang++  -g   CMakeFiles/test_generator.dir/generator/generator.cpp.o CMakeFiles/test_generator.dir/test_utils.cpp.o  -o test_generator -Wl,-rpath,/home/mleoni/PhD/ABI/libcellml/build/src:/home/mleoni/PhD/ABI/libcellml/build/tests/gtest ../src/libcellmld.so.0.1.0 gtest/libgtest_main.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so gtest/libgtest.so -lpthread
```

@IdeaHat: that didn't resolve the issue unfortunately, I am still getting the same error

**Edit 2**
Since the code I am actually trying to compile is [obviously] not that one, I tried to compile this MWE and both GCC and clang link it fine with just `cc A.cpp main.cpp`.

I am now trying to understand what's the difference between this minimal case and the code that I actually have.

Comment: Before anyone else makes that jump, the OP is purposely explicitly instantiating `A::fun<int>()` in A.cpp. Along with the default template argument for `A::fun`, the question is why does one toolchain seem to do the expected (link) and another wouldn't. I'd like to see the build commands for both to ensure something mundane like failing to compile/link A.cpp for one vs. the other isn't the difference. Please update your post to include both build commands.

Comment: OK - how is this code being linked?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: Can you try adding `extern template void A::fun<int>();` to the header?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 0):

I found it. Somewhere in this code base I am not familiar with all classes are marked private by default [as in Windows D:] and after I marked my class public clang could finally link correctly.

Now the plot thickens because with the binaries compiled by clang I see a lot of segfaults in the test suite that are not present when compiled with GCC.

Also, now I have the same question as the one in this thread, except now GCC and clang work fine while MSVC says `unresolved external symbol` :'( .

Comment: appears to be an MSVC issue. I have the same problem.